# Why crontab is using different timezone than my local timezone?

Tags: 20.04, cron

My crontab looks like

```
PATH=/RunCloud/Packages/apache2-rc/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

# some commands here
```

Output of `date` from terminal is `Sun 11 Sep 2022 03:00:00 PM CEST`
I set a cron `5 3 * * * echo date > /home/time.txt` but that does not run at 03:00 of server time

To test crontab, and its timezone, I did

```
* * * * * echo date > /home/time.txt
```

it runs successfully and it outputs same time/timezone as if I type `date` command in terminal

This means my cron syntax is correct and timezones are same for crontab and terminal, what could be wrong then?

Output of `lsb_release` is

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Output of `timedatectl` is

```
               Local time: Sun 2022-09-11 15:44:51 CEST
           Universal time: Sun 2022-09-11 13:44:51 UTC
                 RTC time: Sun 2022-09-11 13:44:50
                Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: it appears cron uses UTC time by default

Comment: @Cagri please read my comment on the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by putting this at the top of your crontab:

```
CRON_TZ=Europe/Berlin
```

You can also verify your `/etc/localtime` is set correctly:

`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime`

As to why, I'm not sure, I'm sure other users will come along soon and help you more if that doesn't  correct the issue.

Comment: `CRON_TZ=Europe/Berlin` fixed my issue, but still wondering what timezone my CRONTAB was running ... I tried to schedule my crons to UTC and they did not run either

Comment: @UmairAyub it should've used UTC. a dirty solution, maybe just put like `0 * * * * touch /tmp/0.txt` ... for every hour to figure it out?

Comment: @Cagri copying from my question "To test crontab, and its timezone, I did

`* * * * * echo date > /home/time.txt` it runs successfully and it outputs same time/timezone as if I type `date` command in terminal"

Comment: @UmairAyub yeah but date is not cron date. so if you tell cron to run at hour 0 and touch 0.txt, and it runs at hour 01:00 UTC, you will know cron timezone is UTC-1, just an idea